# Keep special order/sort by map

Tags: java, sorting, dictionary, comparator, treemap

I have `listAA` object with special order from databases (sort by columnA ask).

Now I would get related data to each object from this list an the same order like in the `listAA`.
When I'm trying `TreeMap` or `HashMap`, I lose this special sort. 
Can I implement a `Comparator`, because I don't have values in the correct special order in this map (`TreeMap`) anymore.

Example:

```
listAA has {
    2,  "x"; 
    3,  "a"; 
    1,  "b"; 
    10, "c"
}
```

Now I need a map with key-order: `2,3,1,10` and not `1,2,3,10`.
How can I achieve this?

My code is, to try to implement a comparator, but I can´t compare values within map, cause I don't have some logic for this.

```
SortedMap<ObjectA, List<ObjectB>> objectAWithObjectBvalues = new TreeMap<ObjectA, List<ObjectB>>(
    new Comparator<long>()
    {
           public int compare(long o1, long o2)
           {
               //i dont know special order anymore here
               return o1.compareTo(o2);
           } 
    }
);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a [`LinkedHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) :

> Hash table and linked list implementation of the Map interface, **with predictable iteration order.** [...] which is normally the order in which keys were inserted into the map

(emphasis mine)